# jquery plugin method ands callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a basic plugin that populates an array within the plugin. How can I get that array via a method call with parameters. This is my first plugin so please go easy on me if this is a dumb question.

basic Plugin

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
        return this.each(function(){
            tagArray = []; // my array that is populated
            //code that does stuff to populate array
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

I would like to get the tagArray like so...

```
var arr = $('.className').myPlugin("getArray");
```

Where I can then use that array elsewhere. How can I accomplish this?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me: you're calling a function that creates an array for *every element* (using .each), so for n elements you have n arrays.  Also, your myPlugin function doesn't take a parameter (and I don't see why it would need one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you would need the `"getArray"` parameter.  In any case you need to define only 1 array and make your function return it:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
        var tagArray = [];
        this.each(function(){
            // add something to tagArray
        });
        return tagArray;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: the reason I need to do this is because there are multiple classes that have this plugin attached. There are also several other callback methods that will be involved where I would need to specify.

Answer (score 0):

That's a rather strange requirement, but an easy way to do that if there is only parameter would be something like :

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(param) {
        var tagArray = [],
            elems    = this.each(function(){
                tagArray.push( $(this).text() ); // whatever you do ??
        });
        return param == 'getArray' ? tagArray : elems;
    }    // ^^ if the parameter is passed, return the array, otherwise the elems
})(jQuery);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/eYeg8/)

It's a bit hackish, but it works. You could also just return `this.map(function() {...` to always return an array etc, or read up on how to pass multiple parameters to a plugin and do different things etc. instead of the hardcoded check for `'getArray'` used above.

Comment: My idea was to do something along the lines of jquery sortable and they have a method that returns the array of items in the list. I want to do the same thing in my plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(function($) {

    function Plugin($el, opts){
        this.tagArray = [];

        this.tagArray.push($el.attr('id')) //for testing the retuned instance

        $el.data('myPlugin', this);
    }

    Plugin.prototype.getTagArray = function(){
        return this.tagArray;
    }


    $.fn.myPlugin = function(opts) {
        if($.type(opts) == 'string'){
            var plugin = this.data('myPlugin');
            return plugin[opts]();
        }

        return this.each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);

            new Plugin($this);
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

jQuery(function(){
    $('#e1, #e2, #e3').myPlugin();

    console.log($('#e1').myPlugin('getTagArray'))
    console.log($('#e2').myPlugin('getTagArray'))
    console.log($('#e3, #e1').myPlugin('getTagArray'))
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mEJwV/)

Answer (score 0):

I just finished writing a JQuery Plugin myself and here is the basic structure I settled on:

```
(function (window, document, $, undefined) {

    //Local Methods
    var methods = {
        init : function(options){
            //stuff you want to do when your plugin initializes i.e. when you do $('selector').myPlugin(options)
        },
        getArray: function(){
            //your getArray method. Put your get array logic here
        }
    }

    //Plugin Initialize 
    $.fn.myPlugin  = function(args){

        if ( methods[args] )
        {
            //execute JQuery Plugin Method
            return methods[ args ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        }
        else if ( typeof args === 'object' || ! args ) 
        {
            //Process JQuery Plugin Options
            var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.myPlugin.defaults, args);
            var new_args = new Array(opts);
            return methods.init.apply( this, new_args );
        }
        else 
        {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  args + ' does not exist on myPlugin' );
        }
    };

    //Define Default Options
    $.fn.myPlugin.defaults = {
        option_1: '',
        option_2: '',
        option_n: ''
    }

    //API Methods
    var M = $.myPlugin = function(){};
    $.extend(M, {
        getArray: function(){
            return methods.getArray();
        }
    });

}(window, document, jQuery));
```

Doing this allows you to start your plugin like this (as usual):

```
$('.className').myPlugin(options);
```

and/or call your `getArray` function like this:

```
$.myPlugin.getArray();
```

I hope this helps you get closer to where you want to be.